# How to apply theme in component designer just like that in application project designer implicitly?

Tags: wpf, resources, themes

Say i had a theme file Button.xaml for standard button.

By merged in application resource dictionary it can implicitly applied in application project designer.

But after i move Button.xaml to component project, the component project designer can not implicitly apply the theme file.

How can i make that theme file works implicitly in component project ?

**Update:**
the Themes.xaml as follow

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/StyleLibrary;component/Themes/Shared.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/StyleLibrary;component/Themes/Button.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/StyleLibrary;component/Themes/ComboBox.xaml" />
...




<Application x:Class="ButtonStyleTest.App" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"> 
    <Application.Resources> 
        <ResourceDictionary> 
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/StyleLibrary;component/Themes.xaml"/> 
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
        </ResourceDictionary> 
    </Application.Resources> 
</Application>
```

If i use merged Theme.xaml, the Button look normal in designer, but failed in runtime.
But if i merge Button.xaml, ComboBox one by one, it look normal for both design and runtime.

Comment: This is usaully in my case for some new modules, that test in application project, then move it into component project when completed. This will save some compiling time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New example.

Say that you have a Library called StyleLibrary.
In this Library you have a ResourceDictionary called Button.xaml which looks like this

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="75" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="23" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In the Application we then add a reference to StyleLibrary and in App.xaml we add this.

```
<Application x:Class="ButtonStyleTest.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/StyleLibrary;component/Button.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This style will apply in the Application and in the Libraries both in runtime and in designer.

To the left is my MainWindow. Is has one Button of its own, and then a UserControl from TestLibrary that has two Buttons. To the right is a Window from TestLibrary which contains one UserControl from TestLibrary, all Buttons seem to have the style applied.

[image]

Comment: My problem is that in application project, there is no need to assign Resources in UserControl markup. It just implicitly apply the theme. But if in component level, is it the only way to apply the theme by additionally adding the Resource markup ?

Comment: I tries this in a test app and it worked, or did I missunderstand your question?

Comment: It works by updated version. But if the component project is stand alone, not coexist with application project in a solution, how to accomplish that, any idea ?

Comment: I follow your code, and i found that in designer it look normal, but in runtime, the theme not applied again.

Comment: Strange, looks normal to me. I'll look into it

Comment: I uploaded a picture where all Buttons get the Style applied. I'm unable to reproduce your problem. Are you sure all is rebuilt etc.?

Comment: For your other problem I'm wondering the same myself. The best I can come up with is to add a ResourceDictionary to your project and add the <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/StyleLibrary;component/Button.xaml"/> there. After that the following line would need to get executed somehow: Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;Component/Dictionary1.xaml", UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary);  But I don't know how to do it

Comment: I've found the problem, that i've merged several xaml files(such as Button.xaml,ComboBox.xaml..) in one RessourceDictionary file (named Themes.xaml in StyleLibrary, then merged Themes.xaml into application , this will cause the problem. And If i just merged single Button.xaml into application, the button will be normal. It's very strange, the designer can use the Theme.xaml file and apply it, but in runtime, the application just ignore it.